# How to combine objects in an array by condition in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let dateOfBirth: Date
    let money: Double
}
```

It contains people and how much money they have received or spent.
The array contains 54 such objects.
I need to find all objects with the same name and date fields and sum their money. That is, in the end, I have to get less than 54 records in my array.

Example: 
In the array, there are 3 records with the object John. For example, first, he received $15.0, then spent $7.0, and then received $4.0. For my task, I need to have 1 record in the array instead of 3 (with money filed as $12.0)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: (offtopic) I really recommend to represent money values with `Decimal` not with a `Double`, otherwise you will start losing precision when summing values.

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks for the advice, but it is just an example, I do not use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the array and add them to a dictionary, where the name concatenated with the date of birth will be the key and the sum of the money will be the value.

Assuming your array containing `Person` objects is called `people`:

```
var moneyDictionary = [String:Double]()
for person in people {
    let personKey = "\(person.name)\(person.dateOfBirth)"
    if let personRecord = moneyDictionary[personKey] {
        moneyDictionary[personKey] = personRecord + person.money
    } else {
        moneyDictionary[personKey] = person.money
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let dateOfBirth: Date
    let money: Double
}

let currentDate = Date()
let person = Person(name: "James", dateOfBirth: currentDate, money: 15)
let person1 = Person(name: "James", dateOfBirth: currentDate, money: -7)
let person2 = Person(name: "James", dateOfBirth: currentDate, money: 4)

// array of person objects
let personArray = [person, person1, person2]

// selected person
let selectedPerson = person

// filter with selected person only
var matchingPersons = personArray.filter {
    $0.name == selectedPerson.name && $0.dateOfBirth == selectedPerson.dateOfBirth
}

// extract values
var values = matchingPersons.map { $0.money }

// total
var total = values.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: By the way, you can compare `Date` instances simply by `==`.

Comment: Updated my answer with regards to @Sulthan comment 